# sed extract substring on a match

Tags: sed

I have a text file called `.env` like this:

```
SOME_VAR="value"
SOME_VAR_2="value2"
NODE_ENV="staging"
SOME_VAR_3="value3"
```

I need to extract the string in between `"` and `"` where the line begins with `NODE_ENV=`

In other words, I need the string `staging` from that file.

I tried with `sed` but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
sed -r '/NODE_ENV.*/I!d;s/.*:.(.*).}$/\1/' .env
```

but that's:

```
NODE_ENV="staging"
```

and I need to have

```
staging
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with sed:

```bash
$ sed -n '/^NODE_ENV/s/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"$/\1/p' .env
staging
```

---

- `-n`: suppress printing.
- `/^NODE_ENV/`: select lines starting with `NODE_ENV`.
- `^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"$`: select all characters that are not `"` from the beginning of the line followed by  `"` (`^[^"]*"`), then capture all characters that follow that are not `"` (`\([^"]*\)`), finally select the `"` at the end (`"$`).
- `/\1/p`: replace all with the captured group (`\1`) and print (`p`).

##### With awk

```bash
$ awk -F'"' '/^NODE_ENV/ { print $2 }' .env
staging
```

---

- `-F'"'`: use `"` as separator.
- `/^NODE_ENV/`: select lines starting with `NODE_ENV`.
- `{ print $2 }` print the 2nd column.